# Double Byte (Japanese Character) in joptionpane optionDialog does not appear correctly

Tags: java, swing, unicode, character, joptionpane

I am using .po file for the translation.

in the dialog box the japanese character "。"(period) looks a bit in the middle of the text instead of the bottom of the text. attached is the picture of the dialog box.
Is there anyway to fix this? or it's just the way it is?

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class OptionPane {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                  "このメール送信はご契約送信容量を超える送信となります。なります");
            }
        });
    }

    private OptionPane() {
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: I hope the code above act the same way as my current system. originally I use something like : 
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, xxx.i18n("text"));

in which I have 2 .po file (english and japanese for translation) which will change "text" to whatever the supposed translation in .po fle

Comment: Maybe, it is due to different fonts set in the text editor of your IDE and in the dialog box...If you don't set the font for the dialog box, it will use its default UI font.

Comment: The software I use for PO file is PoEdit, and you can't change the font, it's default. The problem is this type of text works fine on javascript alert, only in java that it changed.

Comment: As I have suggested to you, you need to check the font used in the Java dialog box's code snippet. Print the JOptionPane's `getFont()` method which is inherited from JComponent/Component to see the font name used. Normally for Japanese font support, the default font is `MS Mincho`. Maybe, you can use the Unicode code point `\uFF61` for the half-width ideographic full-stop symbol `｡` instead.

Comment: The Unicode code point `\uFF61` is for the half-width ideographic full-stop symbol `｡` using `MS Mincho` font. The symbol glyph for it should be drawn at the bottom, not at the middle, based on what I see in the Character Map.

Comment: Again, from what I see in your post, the Japanese symbols in the code snippet and in the dialog box are not the same; in the dialog box, they look flat, unlike in the code snippet. So, they are using a different Japanese font. I wonder what font they are using. But still, fonts like `Arial Unicode MS` and `MS Mincho` have a half-width full-stop symbol glyph at the bottom. Probably, something is not right with the font glyph drawing in the dialog box, unless the half-width full-stop `｡` in the sentence is not really the Unicode code point `\uFF61`...

Comment: See whether this works or not: try to replace the Japanese sentence into HTML-formatted string like this: `"<HTML><FONT face=\"Arial Unicode MS\">このメール送信はご契約送信容量を超える送信となります。なります</FONT></HTML>"` See the BugID: http://bugs.sun.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=4458089 Check this as well: http://java.about.com/od/beginnerlevel/a/codepoints2_2.htm

Comment: I think it's font problem, too, because I've heard that some Chinese fonts have period in the middle.  I don't recommend to use half-width period to fix this problem.  (And, my Japanese knowledge recommend to remove "narimasu" after the period...)

Answer (score 0):

The fonts being used are different.  Not only the period, but symbols like 信 are noticeably different.  Thus I don't think you have anything to worry about, however if you want to be sure, test out the program on a Japanese version of Windows.